# I need to run a background request on django app, what is the best way to do this

Tags: python, django

In `index.html` I have a form that accept files

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  dropdown-toggle">Start Validation</button>                                           
</form>
```

Then my app runs some functions to processes these files
The problem is that the page keeps loading and waits for the return response

my `views.py`

```
class MainView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = UploadFileForm()

        return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'form':form})
    
    def post(self, request):
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            uploadedFile = request.FILES['file']

            function_to_processes_the_file(fil=request.FILES['file']) # Takes some time
            
            return redirect('/')
```

So my question is how can I make it process the file in the background without the need to wait for a response, will it need javascript ?

Comment: You can use celery

Comment: yes, but how can I deliver the file from the html form? the form calls the post method at MainView() class, so I want to click on the submit button and stay on the same page without redirecting

Answer (score 0):

Kindly  check [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) and [Using Celery With Django for Background Task Processing](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-celery-with-django-for-background-task-processing--cms-28732). 
 It allows you to start jobs running in the background. I hope this helps you..

Comment: Isn't there a way other than this?, I just want the submit button to call the function without redirecting and waiting for a response

Comment: In my opinion this is a contradiction. You either wait for a response or you redirect directly. If you want the latter, then just place the `function_to_processes_the_file` in its own thread.

Comment: Used Threading, and it works great Thanks! @ChristianK.